# CSS transition on a Javascript image swap

Tags: javascript, html, css, image, transition

I've got a set of images to swap with another set of images in Javascript, but it looks ugly when it snaps between two images. I want them to fade, and I've managed to do this with the webpage background in CSS. Trouble is, I can't get it to work on the images, and I'm not sure why.

Here's the script to change between the images:

```
    function change_img()
{
    document.images.logo.src = "Images/logo(w).png";
    document.images.about.src = "Images/About50(w).png";
    document.images.projects.src = "Images/Projects50(w).png";
    document.images.contact.src = "Images/Contact50(w).png";
}

function change_back()
{
    document.images.logo.src = "Images/logo.png";
    document.images.about.src = "Images/About50.png";
    document.images.projects.src = "Images/Projects50(2).png";
    document.images.contact.src = "Images/Contact50.png";
}
```

That's in the head of the document.
Then we have an example of one of the images to be swapped:

```
<center><img class="transition" name="logo" src="Images/logo.png" height="300" style="z-index:1"></center>
```

That's activated by a mouseover event on one of the other images. There's four to be changed in total.
And finally, the CSS that I thought would trigger the transition:

```
.transition{-webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
            -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
            -ms-transition: all 0.5s ease;
            -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
            transition: all 0.5s ease;}
```

Quite simply, I've stuck the transition rules in a single CSS rule and attributed it to each image. Have I linked it incorrectly somehow? I can't understand why this isn't working..

Answer (score 0):

What CSS can "transit" are CSS properties, not element attributes like `src`.

What you should to is to have two images in the DOM, one for the current image, and one for the new image, and make the latter fade onto the former.

Something like this:

```
function change_img() {
    var img = document.getElementsByName("logo")[0],
        newImg = new Image();
    newImg.name = "logo";
    newImg.src = "Images/logo.png";
    img.parentNode.insertBefore(newImg, img.nextSibling);
    newImg.className = "transition";
    setTimeout(function() {img.parentNode.removeChild(img);}, 500);
    ...
}
```

This is the CSS part:

```
[name="logo"] + img {
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity 0.5s ease;
}
.transition {opacity: 1;}
```

Comment: Any idea where I could link the transition to enable this to work? Like I said I used a very similar technique to change the background colour of the page using the same mouseover events..

Comment: @TomSykes I was updating my answer right away. I'm still not finished.

Comment: I've put the code in, but it doesn't like it... The logo doesn't fade, but it now appears much bigger than it should be for some reason :/

Answer (score 0):

> I've managed to do this with the webpage background in CSS

only webkit browsers support the background fading transition.
so if u wanna use that continue using backgrounds.
assuming the logos to swap are 2 and the size of them is equal .. for example 100pixel:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>talk</title>
<style>
#logo{
 width:100px;
 height:100px;
 -webkit-transition: background-image 1s ease-in-out;
 background-image:url("logo1.png");
}
#logo.anotherLogo {
 background-image:url("logo2.png");
}
</style>
<script>
var swap=function(){
 document.getElementById('logo').classList.toggle('anotherLogo');
}
window.onload=function(){
 document.getElementsByTagName('button')[0].addEventListener('click',swap,false);
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="logo"></div>
<button>swap logo</button>
</body>
</html>
```

solution 2, this one has more support (works on most modern browsers and not just only on webkit browsers)

this needs 2 images inside a div and the use of absolute in the css and as u can see much more css

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>logo</title>
<style>
#logo{
 width:128px;
 height:128px;
}
#logo>img{
 position:absolute;
 width:128px;
 height:128px;
 -webkit-transition:opacity 1s ease-in-out;
}

#logo>img:nth-child(2){
 opacity:0;
}
#logo.anotherLogo>img:nth-child(2){
 opacity:1;
}
#logo.anotherLogo>img:nth-child(1){
 opacity:0;
}
</style>
<script>
var swap=function(){
document.getElementById('logo').classList.toggle('anotherLogo');
}
window.onload=function(){
document.getElementsByTagName('button')[0].addEventListener('click',swap,false);
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="logo">
<img src="logo1.png"/>
<img src="logo2.png"/>
</div>
<button>swap logo</button>
</body>
</html>
```

solution 3

in this case the div container has the background of one of the logos,and a image inside.
it has also the same structure as your `<center><img/></center>` and could probably replace your existing code with less modifications. however the tag "center" is a old tag and shouldnt be used in modern websites.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>logo</title>
<style>
#logo{
 width:128px;
 height:128px;
 background-image:url(logo2.png);
}
#logo>img{
 width:128px;
 height:128px;
 -webkit-transition:opacity 1s ease-in-out;
}
#logo.anotherLogo>img{
 opacity:0;
}
</style>
<script>
var swap=function(){
document.getElementById('logo').classList.toggle('anotherLogo');
}
window.onload=function(){
document.getElementsByTagName('button')[0].addEventListener('click',swap,false);
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="logo">
<img src="logo1.png"/>
</div>
<button>swap logo</button>
</body>
</html>
```

*ifu wanta specific size of a background-image you can use the background-size css

```
background-size:contain;
```

**contain** resizes the image so that the full image is insideyour div

**cover** fills your container

or you can also use width and height

```
background-size:100px 100px;
```

if you want some more help for your multiswap function... just ask.